# Why do I have so many packages that are "newer than version in archive," and how do I downgrade them?

Tags: apt, package-management, downgrade

Two-part question: why do I have so many packages showing "newer than version in archive," and how do I downgrade all of them to the current version in the archive?

Background: I ran the updater (`update-manager-core`) to bring my Ubuntu 14.04 server up to 16.04.1, and now I have tons of packages that are showing "newer than version in archive."  I'm now running into problems installing new software, and need to downgrade all these packages.

The contents of my `sources.list` is as follows:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main multiverse universe restricted
```

The complete list of packages on my system shown as newer than version in archive can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/sZ5Euw5R).  This was generated with `apt-show-versions | grep "newer than version in archive"`.

Comment: Do you still have soruces.list that points to 14.04? /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I copied (because upgrade to 16.04 stumbled with (nvidia) drivers) my old / & /boot over the partitions, but kept my old /var partiton.
Obviously the archive is not in sync with the runtime.
linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic:amd64/trusty-security 3.13.0-101.148 uptodate
linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic:amd64 4.4.0-51.72 newer than version in archive
Downgrading the archive/package instead of the runtime-modules would be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

There's a script for downgrading Ubuntu packages that are marked as `newer than version in archive`. This script require you to install `apt-show-versions`.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-show-versions
```

Script :

```sh
!/bin/sh

TMP=/tmp/downgrade.$$

if [ $USER != "root" ]; then
         echo "downgrade: Only root can do this"
         exit 1
fi
apt-show-versions -i
apt-show-versions |
         fgrep 'newer than version in archive' |
         cut -d' ' -f 1 >$TMP
if [ -s $TMP ]; then
         apt-show-versions -a |
         fgrep -f $TMP |
         cut -d' ' -f 1-3 |
         grep quantal$ |
         cut -d' ' -f 1-2 |
         sed -e 's/ /=/' |
         xargs aptitude -y install
fi
rm $TMP
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/viking/4017577).

Comment: I've tried this script previously, but it is not removing any packages listed as "newer than version in archive".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, any thoughts on the first part of the question: why are all these packages there in the first place?  Is there something I need to look at that could be responsible for all these packages?

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** want to downgrade those packages.

Something in your **/etc/apt/sources.list**, or a file in your **/etc/apt/sources.list.d** folder, point to an old Ubuntu version.

First check, open **Software & Updates**, from the Unity dash, and go to **Other Software** tab. Mine looks like this:

[image]

Edit the first two entries and look at the distribution field. It should say xenial. If it doesn't, edit to say so.

[image]

If that doesn't fix your problem, you'll need to edit your question with a screenshot of your Software & Updates/Other Software window for me to look at, because there may be other entries that need to be checked.

Comment: I updated my question with my sources.list.  I completely pared down whatever was in there previously to the two lines above, ran apt-get update, then ran apt-get autoremove.  Also, I'm not running Ubuntu desktop; I'm running Ubuntu server.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I missed the server part. When you did the upgrade to 16, did you have a question about removing old/unsupported packages (like we do in desktop)? When/where are you seeing this list of software that's newer than the archive? Can you give us a brief idea about what files it's finding? apps? libs? Do you have any .list files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder? Cheers, Al

Comment: Added list of apt-show-versions of newer packages to original post.  It's everything from apt itself to python to vim.  The only contents of my sources.list.d folder are to the repository of the software I'm trying to install (nextcloud, in this case).  The install fails because it cannot install the dependencies required (due to all the "newer" packages).  I haven't added this detail because it is tangential to my original question, though.

Comment: What happens if you change http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/? Cheers, Al